# Text file parsing in java that resembles an XML

Tags: java, xml, text-parsing

Need to read a text file which looks like an XML.The text file comprises of multiple XML files ,with a parent tags .Need to parse the file and line by line and need to write the corresponding elements of the required child tags even repeated multiple times within the parent tag , in a single line, to another text file .Need to write the elements to a next line after the parent tag.I know how to read a file and write the file ,But I am unable to get the logic to read it acording to the requirement .Please help me out .Any help is much appreciated.

1234566546
    AbcdeXYZ-23243423
    1030253498
    23423423423

```
<parentnode xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping" fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:abcde="http://www.abcde.com/ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcde.com/ext /../xmls/XYZ/recordkeeping/abcde-ext.xsd">
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.google.com">1234566546</Child1>
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/UNique">AbcdeXYZ-154555</Child1>
<country countryScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/country-identifier">1030253498</country>
<state stateScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/state-identifier">434343242</state>
</parentnode>

<parentnode xmlns="http://www.fpml.org/FpML-5/recordkeeping" fpmlVersion="5-5" xmlns:abcde="http://www.abcde.com/ext" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.abcde.com/ext /../xmls/XYZ/recordkeeping/abcde-ext.xsd">
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.google.com">1234566546</Child1>
<Child1 Child1Scheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/UNique">AbcdeXYZ-4566545</Child1>
<country countryScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/country-identifier">1030253498</country>
<state stateScheme="http://www.fpml.org/coding-scheme/external/state-identifier">2323232323</state>
</parentnode>
```

Comment: Can't you wrap it all in a root node and then use an xml parser? Otherwise I would find a way to break up the multiple XML files and parse them separately.

Comment: @Danny It should be parsed as a text file .

Comment: @m0skit0  XML parsing is different in comparision to text file parsing right ?

Comment: @Euphoria XML is text. XML parsers handle all of the hard work for you, and should be used if possible when dealing with XML data.

Comment: @Danny  I am currently dealing with the Text file comprising of the multiple XML generated.The text file is an dump of multiple XML

Answer (score 1):

Parsing xml by hand is a painful waste of time.  If will be much easier to just create a temp file with a wrapping  tag and use an xml parser, like this:

```
    Path inputFile = Paths.get("input.xml");
    Path tempFile = Paths.get("temp.xml");
    Path outputFile = Paths.get("output.xml");

    // make a temp file with fixed xml formatting
    Files.write(tempFile, "<root>".getBytes());
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(inputFile, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        Files.write(tempFile, line.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    }
    Files.write(tempFile, "</root>".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);


    // parse xml and build output string
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse(tempFile.toFile());
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    NodeList parents = doc.getElementsByTagName("parentnode");
    for (int i = 0; i < parents.getLength(); i++) {
        NodeList children = parents.item(i).getChildNodes();
        for (int j=0; j<children.getLength(); j++) {
            sb.append(children.item(j).getTextContent() + " ");
        }
    }


    // clean up temp file
    Files.delete(tempFile);


    // write output file
    Files.write(outputFile, sb.toString().getBytes());
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help.But I am trying to parse the text file , which is a dump of a multiple XML files one after another ,please let me know the logic to parse the text file ,with the requirement

Comment: Look at the code I wrote and think about what it is doing and why.

Comment: The only easy way to detect each XML document is to add a root node and then let a XML parser do the hard work, like azurefrog's solution. If the whole file is too big to fit into memory then you can use a SAX or StAX parser instead of DOM. The only alternative would be to parse the XMLs by hand. But that would mean much more work. There should be a very good reason to justify that.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use a Queue structure [**First In First Out**]

Your basic Algo would be like

1. When ever you encounter a tag , use the value follwing it
2. Store the tag in FIFO.
3. Once you encounter closing tag , match the tag stored in FIFO
   if valid then pop  else throw an exception.
4. At the end of parsing your Q must be empty.

Ofcourse, there are other libraries that you can use.